# How to pass ipv6 address in Redis connection

Tags: java, redis, ipv6

I am using Redisclient as following.

```
RedisClient redisClient = new RedisClient(RedisURI.create("redis://fe80::20c:29ff:fec5:a66b:6379"))
```

But it gives error as "Host name cannot be null".

What is wrong in above code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It needed square brackets around ipv6 address as following.

```
RedisClient redisClient = new RedisClient(RedisURI.create("redis://[fe80::20c:29ff:fec5:a66b]:6379"))
```